# how to control wcf secure socket layer version

Tags: wcf, ssl, versioning

**bs"d**

How to enforce any wcf client to use a specific version of ssl.
Is it possible ?

The question also goes for self hosted wcf services, and iis hosted as well.

Or, a way to know what version is currently in use..

**or at least block version 2.0**

Thanks in advance  .